# how to remove a specific value from a linked list java?

Tags: java

```
public class LinkList
{
private Node list;
private int count;  // number of values stored in the list

public LinkList(){
    list = null;
    count = 0;
    }

// Returns number of values in the LinkList
public int count() {
    return count;
}



/*
 * delete all nodes with this value
 * if the count is zero do nothing
 * if count is 1 delete front node (can use front() and ignore return)
 * else travel the list and when found make prev.next cur.next ... return
 * if still in method delete rear node.
 *
 */


public void deleteNode(int value)
{

    }


}


public class Node{

int value;
Node next;

public Node() {
    next=null;
}

public Node(int n, Node nextNode){
    setValue(n);
    setNext(nextNode);
}

public int getValue(){
    return value;
}

public void setValue(int n){
    value = n;
}

public Node getNext(){
    return next;
}

public void setNext(Node node){
    next = node;
}

public boolean equals(Node other) {
    return (this.getValue() == other.getValue());
}

public String toString() {
    return "" + value;
}

}
```

Comment: You should use the existing lists that are available with Java.

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question, in which case you should put show some effort on your part before coming to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to traverse your linked list while the value isn't null. If you come across the value you're trying to delete, delete the node, rework the links, and return. Your function should look like this:

```
public void deleteNode(int value)
{
    if(count == 0) {
        return;
    } else if (count == 1){
        // delete this node. I'm not quite sure what you mean by use front() in your instruction
    } else {
        Node x = Node first; // This should be the first node in the list
        while(x != null && x.next != null) {
            if(x.value == value) {
                if(x == first) {
                    first = x.next; // If your first node is bad, make 2nd node your first node
                } else {
                    prev.next = x.next; // This skips the current node, with the sought-after value
                }
            } else {
                x = x.next; // Traverse to check the next node
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind, you'll need to declare a prev and first node in your node class. Don't think I saw those defined in the given code.

Answer (score 2):

```
                    +------+        +------+        +------+
                    |      |        |      |        |      |
            Step 0  |      |+------>|      |+------>|      |
                    |      |        |      |        |      |
                    |      |        |      |        |      |
                    +------+        +------+        +------+

                               +----------------+
                    +------+   |    +------+    |   +------+
                    |      |+--+    |      |    +-->|      |
            Step 1  |      |        |      |+------>|      |
                    |      |        |      |        |      |
                    |      |        |      |        |      |
                    +------+        +------+        +------+


                    +------+                        +------+
                    |      |                        |      |
            Step 2  |      |+---------------------->|      |
                    |      |                        |      |
                    |      |                        |      |
                    +------+                        +------+
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use Java's existing `ArrayList` implementation. It is in `O(n)` linear time for most operations, with some even being `O(1)`. It also integrates nicely with collections, iterators, and sets.

I would recommend using a doubly-linked list instead. Simply add a `previous` field with required getters and setters.

Then to delete, simply link together the previous and the next around the corrent node. This ie left as an exercise to the reader. (or find it in the revision history)
This simply puts the links back together around the node currently selected.

If you want to use a singly-linked list you have to iterate through the list, and check if next is the node you want to delete. Then you set the next of the current node to nextNode.getNext().

This latter method will be quite inefficient.

Comment: 9/10 times if someone isn't already using the utilities it is because they are trying to gain better understanding or they are students and have to use their own.

Comment: @C.Lang Hence appropriate information was given about doing the task with given resources. This does look like a homework problem, though.